How to add Trusted Sites using GPO in Windows Server 2022
We have Dynamics Great Plains 2018 on Windows Server 2022. When we attempt to log on using modern authentication, we encounter a pop-up indicating that content is blocked for https://login.microsoftonline.com.
I Internet Explorer, we checked Internet Options > Security > Trusted Sites, but the option to add sites manually is dimmed.
We have a Group Policy Object (GPO) configured for the Site to Zone Assignment List, where we  added  https://login.microsoftonline.com to Zone 2 Trusted Sites. Despite this, the issue persists.
There is a workaround where we can disable Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration, but we prefer not to turn it off.
Is there a way to add https://login.microsoftonline.com to Trusted Sites without disabling IE Enhanced Security?

Internet Explorer is end of life, however, the version of IE that uses those Group Policy administrative templates were obsolete many years ago.
Internet Explorer 10 and 11 used a more modern Group Policy Preference settings.
See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/browsers/administration/how-to-configure-group-policy-preference-settings
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/blog/windows-itpro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/2366549
